# Css and JS image zoom on scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I found this really cool app and it has a few features that I can't figure out.

One in particular is the image zoom on scroll up so that you don't see "behind" the app. [I included a video demo here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3J3yMn8Jad4TFlZWERuX3BYTVE/view?usp=sharing)

I don't know if they have the image set to the background, or if the image is in another container. I am talking about the top picture of Batman.

I'm new to js and haven't been able to see any solutions that would point me in the right direction!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You could do a similar animation with CSS and JS.

Comment: That's the plan. If you can point me in the right direction that would help a lot.

Comment: try Skrollr.js, here's a sample - https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
This would do all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: Right away the first thing would be to place the image as a css background-image for a container and apply a background-size:cover; I'm still thinking of a way to ensure this container fill the gap above on scroll. jquery on.scroll function could work, but it maybe a little to heavy...

Comment: I thought the same as @Niall Mather about using skrollr, maybe to make the container fill the gap between the viewport top and the content top.

Comment: Here I found a tutorial how to do it here - https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-zoom-into-an-image-on-scroll/

Comment: I actually saw that too but that isn't the same functionality as the video. I'll have to mess with that and see if I can repurpose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are probably building into how far you've scrolled down the page. For example, you can get the distance the user has scrolled with:

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
```

If you bound this into the scroll event, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop);
}, false)
```

Then you can alter the size of some image based on how far you've scrolled down. Here's an example of how this could be used to change the size of some image:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
 var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
 image = document.getElementById("theImage");
    var dimension = 100 + 400 - Math.min(400,scrollTop) + "%";
    image.style.backgroundSize = dimension+" "+dimension;
}, false)
```

```css
#theImage {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/sports/');
  background-position: center; 
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="theImage">
</div>
<h1>Some text</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed ante elementum, ornare nibh nec, finibus purus. Donec eu hendrerit orci. Vivamus fermentum, quam sed vulputate semper, est orci mollis leo, non pharetra nisi ante sit amet lorem. Nulla condimentum metus vitae nulla fringilla, dapibus dignissim lacus commodo. Etiam tincidunt urna sit amet odio mollis, eget vestibulum odio iaculis. Praesent vel est malesuada, efficitur eros ut, pellentesque metus. In sagittis tincidunt ligula. Donec sit amet ipsum libero. Donec quis dolor ut eros maximus finibus molestie a lorem.</p>
```

Comment: I've now changed it to have a zooming effect rather than a resizing effect.

Comment: That pretty close! I should be able to tweak this! Thanks! The only difference in the app is the image only resized when scrolling past the screen on that rubber band effect. I think it is hard to do in a web browser because you can't really over scroll.

Comment: Basically I just need to reverse the effect to work when the user pulls the screen down and not just the normal scroll.